# Swift Siesta transformer pipeline distinguish between `/path/{id}` and `/path/special-token`

Tags: siesta-swift

Suppose I am setting up my transformers and need to handle two similar API routes that return different object schemas, e.g.

```
/beers/{id}               -> [Beer]
/beers/grouped-by-country -> [Country:Beer]
```

It seems Siesta is unable to distinguish in this type of case, because the path matching only supports basic glob. So the best we can do is

```
service.configureTransformer("/beers/*") { ... }
service.configureTransformer("/beers/grouped-by-country") { ... }
```

And of course, `/beers/*` will also match `/beers/grouped-by-country`, so it will try to parse the response into the wrong object type.

Is there a way to distinguish the routes in this case?